# javascript variable calling not working on this following code

Tags: javascript

Those following code isnot working...
Firstly i want these selected value (by sentvalue() and receivevalue())
and then want to use those selected value on another(sent()) function ..

this is html code--

```
<select class="form-control"  id="sents" onchange="sentvalue(this) " >
        <option value="0" >-- Select One --</option>
        <option value="1" ">1</option>
        <option value="2" >2</option>
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4" >4</option>
        <option value="5" >5</option>
        <option value="6" >6</option>
        <option value="7" >7</option>

       </select>
        <select class="form-control" id="receives" onchange=" receivevalue(this); counter2(this); " >
        <option value="0">-- Select One --</option>
        <option value="1" onclick="i();">1</option>
        <option value="2" >2</option>
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4" >4</option>
        <option value="5" >5</option>
        <option value="6" >6</option>
        <option value="7" >7</option>

       </select>
<input type="number" id="sent2" onkeyup="sent()" class="form-control" name="number">
<p class="form-control" id="receive2" type="number" name="number" disabled>
```

i want to use receivevalue() and sentvalue() on sent() function but it does not work...

```
var x,y;
function receivevalue(selv) {

var y = selv.options[selv.selectedIndex].value;}
function sentvalue(selv) {

var x= selv.options[selv.selectedIndex].value;
}

    function sent(){
        receivevalue();
        gett=y;
        sentvalue();
        putt=x;
        if(gett==1 && putt==1){
            var userinput=document.getElementById('sent2').value;
            var news=(userinput/88).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('receive2').innerHTML=news;
        }
    }
```

i want sentvalue() variable x and receivevalue() variable y on sent() function . please solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
function sent(){
        rselv = document.getElementById('receives');
        receivevalue(rselv);
        get=y;
        sselv = document.getElementById('sents')
        sentvalue(sselv);
        put=x;
        if(get==1 && put==1){
            var userinput=document.getElementById('sent2').value;
            var news=(userinput/88).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('receive2').innerHTML=news;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is typo in **sentevalue**. It should be **sentvalue**.

Then your x, y variables are global. You shouldn't re-declare them inside function.

```
var x,y;

function receivevalue(selv) {
    y = selv.options[selv.selectedIndex].value;
}

function sentvalue(selv) {
    x = selv.options[selv.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Now since you have values x and y in global variables, sent function can simply be written like this.

```
function sent(){
 if(x==1 && y==1){
  var userinput=document.getElementById('sent2').value;
  var news=(userinput/88).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('receive2').innerHTML=news;
 }
}
```

And Correct HTML is:

```
<select class="form-control"  id="sents" onchange="sentvalue(this)">
 <option value="0" >-- Select One --</option>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
  <option value="6" >6</option>
  <option value="7" >7</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="receives" onchange="receivevalue(this); counter2(this);">
  <option value="0">-- Select One --</option>
  <option value="1" onclick="i();">1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
  <option value="6" >6</option>
  <option value="7" >7</option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="sent2" onkeyup="sent()" class="form-control" name="number">

<p class="form-control" id="receive2" type="number" name="number" disabled>
```

Comment: There were some typos in HTML, I assumed it would be because of copy-paste. Now can you please try.